# Given a subgroup $G$ of the group $(M_2(\mathbb{C}), +)$ find an injective morphism between the groups $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ and $(G, +)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, complex-numbers

Consider the following subgroup of the group of matrices $(M_2(\mathbb{C}), +)$:

$$ G = \Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}
z_1 & z_2\\
-\overline{z_2} & \overline{z_1}\\
\end{pmatrix} \Bigg | \hspace{.1cm} z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}
\Bigg\} \subseteq M_2(\mathbb{C})$$

I am asked to find an injective morphism between the groups $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ and $(G, +)$.

So what I understood is that I have to find a function $f$

$$f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow G$$

that has the following properties:

$I. f(z_1 + z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2), \hspace{.3cm} \forall \hspace{.1cm} z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

$II. f$ is injective

So then, without any strategy in particular, I started coming up with different functions and checked to see if they had the above properties. I came up with this function:

$$f(z) = \begin{pmatrix}
z & z\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I observed that:

$$f(z_1 + z_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
z_1 + z_2 & z_1 + z_2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$f(z_1) + f(z_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
z_1 & z_1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
+
\begin{pmatrix}
z_2 & z_2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 + z_2 & z_1 + z_2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So we have that $f(z_1 + z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$, therefore the function $f$ is a morphism and also the first property is satisfied. Now we have to check the second property.

If we would have $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, we would have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 & z_1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
z_2 & z_2\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And that would result in the fact $z_1 = z_2$ so the function is indeed injective. Since the statement of the problem is set up in such a way, I assumed that the function needs to be injective, while also not being surjective, so I also checked to make sure that $f$ is not surjective.

Say we have $A \in G$ such that $f(z) = A$. We would have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
z & z\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
z_1 & z_2\\
-\overline{z_2} & \overline{z_1}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which would only happen when $z_1 = z_2 = z = 0$ so I concluded that the function $f$ is **not** surjective.

So, given everything I have shown, we have that the function:

$$f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow G \hspace{2cm} f(z) = \begin{pmatrix}
z & z\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

is an injective (and also not surjective) morphism between the groups $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ and $(G, +)$.

Is my work correct? I am full of doubt about it. It seems so random, I didn't even follow any approach to finding the function, I just did trial and error. And is this function that I found really an injective morphism? In a nutshell, is my solution correct?

Comment: Your matrix $\left(\matrix{z & z\\ 0 & 0}\right)$ must belong to G for all z. It is not always of the form of an element of G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ contains the matrix, $J_z=\begin{pmatrix}z&0\\0&\bar z\end{pmatrix}$
, for any$z\in\Bbb C$.

Map $z\to J_z$.

Comment: So my function's output does not belong to $G$ for all $z$ and therefore cannot be a proper function, given that domain. But if we consider your mapping, that matrix form does belong to $G$. On the one hand, it is evidently injective and on the other hand, if we would try to solve the equation $f(z)=A$ with $A\in\mathbb{G}$ we would get that $z=z_1\Rightarrow z\in\mathbb{C}$ and that $z_2=0$ and because $z_2$ can only equal $0$, the function is not surjective. Is that right? I understand the injectivity of the function, but I'm still not sure that it lacks surjectivity, as it should.

Comment: That is right.  The function isn't surjective, clearly, for the reason you gave.